# add a table view to a table view cell in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to implement this type of screen. There are two table view one is in right side another one is in left side. In left side table (chatOne) view I want to add a table view in its first section (that is chatOneCell). 
[image: screen]

How to add a table view to a table view cell in swift?

I am trying to add a table view to a table view cell. The outer table is shown successfully .But the inner table is not loading. if i am adding view, Button labels etc. It is showing in the cell but not the table view. Please see my code and help me to rectify my problem

ChatOne is the cell of outer table view

InerTable is the table which i am trying to place in chatOne Cell

insideCell is the cell of inerTable

iner table has tag 45 and ouer has tag 25

```
        class ChatOne: UITableViewCell{

            @IBOutlet weak var inerTable: UITableView!


            override func awakeFromNib() {
                super.awakeFromNib()


                inerTable.dataSource = self as? UITableViewDataSource
                inerTable.delegate = self as? UITableViewDelegate
               inerTable.reloadData()

            }

           }

        class insideCell: UITableViewCell {
            @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
            override func awakeFromNib() {
                super.awakeFromNib()

            }
        }



        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                if tableView.tag == 45{
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! insideCell
                    cell.myLabel.text = "Tapan"
                    return cell
                }
                if tableView.tag == 25{

                    let rowIdentifier = tableOneIdentifire[indexPath.section]
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: rowIdentifier)
                    return cell!
                }


                return UITableViewCell()

            }
```

Comment: you need to implement tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {} method in ChatOne calss and return InerTable data source count. Why your cellForRowAt method is not inside the ChatOne class?

Comment: You must add the table view dataSource and delegate methods in ChatOne class that contains a table view.

Comment: Have you implemented delegate for inner table ?

Comment: also could you share why you need table inside table? maybe there is easier way

Comment: 1. class ChatOne: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
2.Implement delegate for inter table

Comment: extension ChatOne{

    func setTableViewDataSourceAndDelegate<d: UITableViewDataSource & UITableViewDelegate>(_ datasourceDelegate: d, forRow row: Int) {
        inerTable.delegate = datasourceDelegate
        inerTable.dataSource = datasourceDelegate
        inerTable.reloadData()
    } }

Comment: i have implemented delegate like this

Comment: i have edited the question and added a image of the screen

Comment: Do not include images of code!

Comment: I am successfully implemated the tableview in tableview cell.how to make the cell size will according to the inner table view.the cell will expand as the table view size will increase

Answer (score 0):

I also have this kind of problems in adding table views in swift . so I follow this link and there are all the details clearly . so follow this [shorturl.at/yKSYZ](http://shorturl.at/yKSYZ)